# user servicesidekick API using PHP

Tags: php, web-services, api

I want to use the servicesidekick API using php, as per their documentation at here: http://www.servicesidekick.com/help/api

They are suggesting to use curl for this. I am suppose to get xml file in response.

Below is my code:

```
exec('command',$data);
```

when I print the $data then its giving each line of xml in each element of Array. But i want it to be accessed as the XML file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) functions to make things easy. Here is a very basic example that prints out some comma-deimited fields:

```
<?php

$token   = "123xxx";
$account = "myaccount";
$url     = "https://{$token}:{$token}@{$account}.servicesidekick.com/jobs.xml";

$xml = simplexml_load_string(file_get_contents($url));

foreach ($xml->children() as $job) {
  echo "{$job->id},{$job->name},{$job->{"job-number"}},{$job->{"balance-remaining"}} \n";
}

?>
```

It's pretty easy to get access to all of the fields. This example just demonstrates jobs, but all of the entities can be called the same way. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Please read the docs of the [PHP curl bindings](http://php.net/curl).

There is no function `curl()` which does lots of magic like you apparently assume in your code.